# R: Filter rows based on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
>dfMapping
Name Number
a    10
b    20
c    15


>dfMapping2
Name Total Type 
a    112    x
a    20     y
a    1      z
b    10     x
b    120    z
c    11     z
c    100    x
```

From `dfMapping2` I want only those rows where `dfMapping2$Total > dfMapping$Number` and the final `Total` should have `Total - dfMapping$Number`. So, here the result should be:

```
>result
Name  Total  Type
a     102    x
a     10     y
b     100    z
c     85     x
```

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: two steps?: 1) merge on Name to make DF 2)DF[DF$Total>DF$Number,]

Comment: Are you sure the result you show is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Stephan's solution. Step 1: merge dataframe. Step 2: filter based on condition.

```
df <- merge(dfMapping, dfMapping2)
df <- with(df, df[Total > Number,])
```

Which generates:

```
  Name Number Total Type
1    a     10   112    x
2    a     10    20    y
5    b     20   120    z
7    c     15   100    x
```

Comment: Just two lines: `df[,3] <- (df[,3]-df[,2])` to rest the values and then `df <- df[,-2]` to get just the Name Total and Type columns